# Scraping attributes from drop down sub menu

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape specific Data from a website. The data exists only in drop down sub menu of another drop down, and gets generated only after selecting specific option of main drop down menu.
I am using Select class of selenium to click through both menus- that functionality works properly. However I have a problem with scraping the data.

I have confirmed that the Data gets generated by saving full soup.prettify to a file and finding it there. However whenever I use soup.find(), soup.findAll() or other searches I receive empty object or empty list

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


login = {
"handle": "login",
"pass": "password"
}

def ScanBot():
    driver.get('http://www.swcombine.com/members/cockpit/travel/index.php?tft=Hyperspace')
    sleep(3)
    sectorOptions = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('sectors')).options
    for i in range (1, len(sectorOptions)):
        Select(driver.find_element_by_name('sectors')).select_by_index(i)
        sleep(3)
        list = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('systemID')).options
        for b in range (1, len(list)):
            #Select(driver.find_element_by_name('systemID')).select_by_index(b)
            text = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
            print(soup.find_all('select','id="systemID"'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9150")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
LaunchBot(login)
ScanBot()
```

---

Prints only [] empty results for each iteration

```html
<select name="systemID" id="systemID" onchange="setCoordsFromSystem()">
    <option data-galx="71" data-galy="-166">-- System --</option>
    <option data-galx="-24" data-galy="-76">Abregado</option>
    <option data-galx="-26" data-galy="-86">Belgaroth</option>
    <option data-galx="-38" data-galy="-87">Delphon</option>
    <option data-galx="-24" data-galy="-81">Dentaal</option>
    <option data-galx="-19" data-galy="-87">Diamal</option>
    <option data-galx="-21" data-galy="-70">Eamus</option>
    <option data-galx="-10" data-galy="-72">Frego</option>
    <option data-galx="0" data-galy="-82">Iphigin</option>
    <option data-galx="-19" data-galy="-74">Plexis</option>
    <option data-galx="-30" data-galy="-80">Steelious</option>
</select>
```

This is part of the source code that I need to get ahold of
Best would be to return list as follows:

-24,-76 Abregado

-26,-86 Belgaroth

etc etc

Thank you very much for any assistance

Comment: You must login with selenium and then begin the scrape.

Comment: Aye, Ive cut out all the code that works to keep it simple

Comment: re added the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `print(soup.find_all('select','id="systemID"'))` part
change it with :

```
print(soup.find_all('select',attrs ={'id':'systemID'}))
```

You will see the the goal output
And you can reach the datas like :

```
datas =soup.find_all('select',attrs ={'id':'systemID'})

for all1 in datas:
    option = all1.find_all('option')
    for getdatas in option:
        print (getdatas.text)
        print (getdatas['data-galx'])
        print (getdatas['data-galy'])
```

OUTPUT :

```
-- System --
71
-166
Abregado
-24
-76
Belgaroth
-26
-86
Delphon
-38
-87
Dentaal
-24
-81
Diamal
-19
-87
Eamus
-21
-70
Frego
-10
-72
Iphigin
0
-82
Plexis
-19
-74
Steelious
-30
-80
```